# Vue equivalent of setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a shopping cart system with Laravel and Vue. When I add an item to the basket, I display a confirmation message by toggling a Vue variable being watched by a v-if:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" v-if="basketAddSuccess" transition="expand">Added to the basket</div>
```

And the JS:

```
addToBasket: function(){
                item = this.product;
                this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
                this.basketAddSuccess = true;
            }
```

(And yes, I will be adding this in a then-catch shortly).

This works fine and the message appears. However, I'd like the message to disappear again after a certain time, say a few seconds. How can I do this with Vue? I've tried `setTimeOut` but Vue doesn't seem to like it, saying it's undefined.

EDIT: I was misspelling `setTimeout` like an idiot. However, it still doesn't work:

My function is now:

```
addToBasket: function(){
                item = this.photo;
                this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
                this.basketAddSuccess = true;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    this.basketAddSuccess = false;
                }, 2000);
            }
```

Comment: try `setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.basketAddSuccess = false;
                }, 2000);`

Comment: Probably, `this` inside the `setTimeout` doesn't refer to the main object.

Comment: @akinuri Using ES6 and arrow function `this` should refers to the correct scope. This was a problem before solved with the typical `var self=this`. Please correct me if im wrong. Not tested.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

### Arrow Function

The best and simplest way to solve this problem is by using an arrow function `() => {}`:

```js
    addToBasket() {
        var item = this.photo;
        this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
        this.basketAddSuccess = true;
        // now 'this' is referencing the Vue object and not the 'setTimeout' scope
        setTimeout(() => this.basketAddSuccess = false, 2000);
    }
```

This works because the `this` of arrow functions is [bound to the `this` of its *enclosing scope*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)- in Vue, that's the parent/ enclosing component. Inside a traditional function called by `setTimeout`, however, [`this` refers to the `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem) (which is why you ran into errors when you tried to access `this.basketAddSuccess` in that context).

### Argument Passing

Another way of doing this would be passing `this` as an arg to your function through [`setTimeout`'s prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Syntax) using its `setTimeout(callback, delay, arg1, arg2, ...)` form:

```js
    addToBasket() {
        item = this.photo;
        this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
        this.basketAddSuccess = true;
        //Add scope argument to func, pass this after delay in setTimeout
        setTimeout(function(scope) {
             scope.basketAddSuccess = false;
        }, 2000, this);
    }
```

(It's worth noting that the arg passing syntax is incompatible with IE 9 and below, however.)

### Local Variable

Another *possible*, but less eloquent and less encouraged, way is to bind `this` to a var outside of `setTimeout`:

```js
    addToBasket() {
        item = this.photo;
        this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
        this.basketAddSuccess = true;
        //Declare self, which is accessible inside setTimeout func
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
             self.basketAddSuccess = false;
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Using an arrow function would eliminate the need for this extra variable entirely however, and really should be used unless something else is preventing its use.

Comment: This should use an arrow function instead of using self to refer to this

Comment: What if the user meanwhile changes the component/page and current (this/self...) component is destroyed?

Comment: If you need more complex behavior handling, with timeout/wait, cancel handling, change page, debounce, ecc.  is better use something like RxJS or similar.
You can begin here: https://rxmarbles.com/

Comment: The arrow function does not work in IE11 and below. The latter two solutions do.

Comment: well, what do you know - the arrow function works for me instead of regular function :)

Answer (score 102):

after encountering the same issue, I ended up on this thread. For future generation's sake: The current up-most voted answer, attempts to bind "this" to a variable in order to avoid changing the context when invoking the function which is defined in the setTimeout.

An alternate and more recommended approach(using Vue.JS 2.2 & ES6) is to use an arrow function in order to bind the context to the parent (Basically "addToBasket"'s "this" and the "setTimeout"'s "this" would still refer to the same object):

```
addToBasket: function(){
        item = this.photo;
        this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
        this.basketAddSuccess = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.basketAddSuccess = false;
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 31):

Add bind(this) to your setTimeout callback function

```
setTimeout(function () {
    this.basketAddSuccess = false
}.bind(this), 2000)
```

Answer (score 20):

ES6 can bind 'this'

```
setTimeout(() => {

 },5000);
```

Answer (score 7):

Kevin Muchwat above has the BEST answer, despite only 10 upvotes and not selected answer.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    this.basketAddSuccess = false
}.bind(this), 2000)
```

Let me explain WHY.

"Arrow Function" is ECMA6/ECMA2015. It's perfectly valid in compiled code or controlled client situations (cordova phone apps, Node.js), and it's nice and succinct. It will even probably pass your testing!

However, Microsoft in their infinite wisdom has decided that Internet Explorer WILL NOT EVER SUPPORT ECMA2015!

Their new Edge browser does, but that's not good enough for public facing websites.

Doing a standard function(){} and adding .bind(this) however is the ECMA5.1 (which IS fully supported) syntax for the exact same functionality.

This is also important in ajax/post .then/else calls. At the end of your .then(function){}) you need to bind(this) there as well so:  .then(function(){this.flag = true}.bind(this))

I would have added this as a comment to Kevin's response, but for some silly reason it takes less points to post replies than to comment on replies

DO NOT MAKE THE SAME MISTAKE I MADE!

I code on a Mac, and used the 48 points upvoted comment which worked great! Until I got some calls on my scripts failing and I couldn't figure out why. I had to go back and update dozens of calls from arrow syntax to function(){}.bind(this) syntax.

Thankfully I found this thread again and got the right answer. Kevin, I am forever grateful.

As per the "Accepted answer", that has other potential issues dealing with additional libraries (had problems properly accessing/updating Vue properties/functions)

Comment: With Edge moving to Chromium, soon enough this won't be an issue (finally)

Comment: @dave Not sure how that makes any difference when the argument is that IE doesn't support this. Edge has supported this since 2015.

Comment: And you can always use an EcmaScript transpiler like babel to have your arrow functions converted to support IE.

Answer (score 5):

vuejs 2

first add this to methods

```
methods:{
    sayHi: function () {
      var v = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        v.message = "Hi Vue!";
    }, 3000);
   }
```

after that call this method on mounted

```
mounted () {
  this.sayHi()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Vue.nextTick

```
addToBasket: function(){
                item = this.photo;
                this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
                this.basketAddSuccess = true;
                Vue.nextTick(() =>{
                    this.basketAddSuccess = false;
                });
            }
```

Comment: You can wrap nexTick under setTimeout

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for `bind(this)` when you are using arrow functions:

```
  setTimeout( ()=> {
    // some code
   }, 500)
```

Answer (score 4):

### Arrow Function

The best and simplest way to solve this problem is by using an arrow function `() => {}`:

```js
    addToBasket() {
        var item = this.photo;
        this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
        this.basketAddSuccess = true;
        // now 'this' is referencing the Vue object and not the 'setTimeout' scope
        setTimeout(() => this.basketAddSuccess = false, 2000);
    }
```

This works because the `this` of arrow functions is [bound to the `this` of its *enclosing scope*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)- in Vue, that's the parent/ enclosing component. Inside a traditional function called by `setTimeout`, however, [`this` refers to the `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem) (which is why you ran into errors when you tried to access `this.basketAddSuccess` in that context).

### Argument Passing

Another way of doing this would be passing `this` as an arg to your function through [`setTimeout`'s prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Syntax) using its `setTimeout(callback, delay, arg1, arg2, ...)` form:

```js
    addToBasket() {
        item = this.photo;
        this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
        this.basketAddSuccess = true;
        //Add scope argument to func, pass this after delay in setTimeout
        setTimeout(function(scope) {
             scope.basketAddSuccess = false;
        }, 2000, this);
    }
```

(It's worth noting that the arg passing syntax is incompatible with IE 9 and below, however.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the this keyword in your function, you need to write the setTimeout function in ES6

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.filters.max_budget_gt_eq = this.budgetHigherValue;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this.animationStop`, not use this.animationStop <s>**( )**</s>

```
animationRun(){
    this.sliderClass.anim = true;
    setTimeout(this.animationStop, 500);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a scope issue. Try the following instead:

```
addToBasket: function(){
    item = this.photo;
    this.$http.post('/api/buy/addToBasket', item);
    this.basketAddSuccess = true;
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        self.basketAddSuccess = false;
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

please use setInterval like below:

```
    setInterval(()=>{this.checkOrder()},2000);
```