# Understanding while-loops in Vue with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm quite new with Vue. This is confusing the hell out of me.

If I have this while-loop inside of a method.

```
methods: {
  test: function() {
    counter = 0;
    while( counter < 10 ){
      console.log( counter );
      counter++;
      window.setTimeout( function() {
        console.log( 'Test' );
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.test();
}
```

Then in my console, it will print this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

(10) Test
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't it write this:

```
0
Test
1
Test
2
Test
3
Test
4
Test
5
Test
6
Test
7
Test
8
Test
9
Test
```

... And do it with a seconds delay in-between?

The reason why I'm asking is that I'm pulling data from an API, - and only want to initialize a function, when the data has been populated.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399050/vue-equivalent-of-settimeout), suggest using arrow-functions for the setTimeout, but I'm not seeing any difference when doing it.

And I've looked a lot at [Vue's lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html), but that didn't show me the answer either.

Comment: `setTimeout` does not stop execution of the code. Imagine setting a timeout as setting a kitchen timer; the browser will still do stuff (in this case, continue the while loop) while it waits for the timer to go off.

Comment: You might also want to read up on JavaScript Promises and async/await. Especially if you're doing API calls you usually want to wait with your function execution until the call has finished. Promises give you an easy and standardised way to do so. [This example](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions#async_return_values) might be relevant to your current case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counting in the while loop happens really fast (< 1 second), so by the time the timeout executes the rest of your while loop has already executed (printing 0 to 9), after that your timeouts reach their countdown and also print 'Test' consecutively. This causes it to be printed 10 times after each other which in the console is abbreviated with the prefix (10) instead of printing test literally 10 times.

This happens because when you call `window.setTimeout` the code called here will be executed after x miliseconds **in parallel**, thus the rest of your code continues to process while the timeout is counting down.

If you want the result you expected you should execute it directly and not use a timeout:

```
methods: {
  test: function() {
    counter = 0;
    while( counter < 10 ){
      console.log( counter );
      counter++;
      console.log( 'Test' );
    }
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.test();
}
```

If you want to wait 1 second between every number you should use a recursive function, something like this:

```
test(0);

function test (counter) {
    if (counter < 10) {
       console.log( counter );
       counter++;
       console.log( 'Test' );
       window.setTimeout( function() {
          test(counter);
       }, 1000)
    }
}
```

Make sure to use an initial or default value of `0` for this

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I'm after a function that executes once every second. How do I stop/pause the execution of the next while-loop?

Comment: @Zeth, I updated the answer, if anything is unclear please let me know :)

Comment: In that case make sure to call `test` either with an initial value of `0` or use `0` as a default value for the `counter` argument.

Comment: @Padarom, yes of course :). But you're right, that might be good to add to the answer. I updated my answer

Comment: I would suggest an Async solution specially because he fetches something from the API instead of this whole `while if for` messy stuff

Comment: @Badgy, I agree but that is a completely different discussion/subject since that goes into the concept of async/promise and does not relate to the question which is about understanding how and why the timeout does/does not work, and I did not want to go offtopic too much. If this is something the OP wants to know more about it should be a new question otherwise it will get too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can use is a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise). The **getApi** function should be modified and read the API and using a promise to execute it in parallel, so I would call the **then** once the load is finished...

```
methods: {
  test: function() {
    this.getAPI().then((data) => {
       // here is the API load finished | data === 'example data' 
    });
  },
  getAPI: function(){
    // change this
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve('example data');
    });
  }

},
mounted() {
  this.test();
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of the OP completely, would you consider also adding an explanation of how a delay between the API calls can be achieved correctly? Because this is an important part of the question